# Coding multiple lists and Loops

Tags: python, list, loops, psychopy

For my experiment, I am creating a simple reaction time test. It will have 4 blocks, with 6 trials in each. I have managed to present the first trial of a block on screen, albeit for a practice round (the stimuli does appear however). However, I am not sure whether I should be creating a number of lists (i.e. to hold the different stimuli for the different trials) or if I should be altering the characteristics of my one existing loop. My code is below:

```
from psychopy import visual, core, event #import some libraries from PsychoPy
import psychopy.event

#Create the code for saving the data at some point


#create a window
mywin = visual.Window([1920,1080], monitor="testMonitor", units="deg")
mywin.update()

# create the six stimuli:
Target = visual.TextStim(mywin, text = "text default")
text_stim_list = [] # a list to hold them
Stim_text = ["Berlin", "Paris", "London", "Nice", "Vienna", "Charming"] # 
their content

#the positions of the stimuli
positions = [
 (-10, 10),
 (10, 10),
 (-10, -10),
 (10, -10),
 (-1, -10),
 (1, 10),
 ]

 #Initial message to participants about the study 
 message1 = visual.TextStim(mywin, text = "You have been captured by the 
 plotters. As a test to see if you have information regarding the event, an 
on screen test will be adminstered. Press Spacebar when ready")
message1.draw()
mywin.update()

#this will wait for a button press confirmation from p's to continue
response = event.waitKeys(keyList = ['space',], timeStamped = True)

#Initial message to participants about the study 
message1 = visual.TextStim(mywin, text = "On the next screen, you will be 
presented with a practice round of stimuli. Press Q if any of the cities are 
familiar, or press P if you do not recognise the cities")
message1.draw()
mywin.update()

#this will wait for a button press confirmation from p's to continue
response = event.waitKeys(keyList = ['space',], timeStamped = True)

#Loop for drawing the stimulus 
#code for the keyboard response
keys = psychopy.event.waitKeys(keyList=["q", "p"])

#Practice round-should it be stopped by a button press?

for frameN in range(7*60):
# draw each stim *on each frame*
for i in range(len(Stim_text)):
    Target.setPos(positions[i])
    Target.setText(Stim_text[i])
    Target.draw()
# now flip the window (after all stimuli drawn)
mywin.flip()

 #Initial message to participants about the study 
message1 = visual.TextStim(mywin, text = "On the next screen, the cities 
which 
our intelligence tells us are at risk will be presented. Press Q if any are 
familiar, press P if not blah blah blah.. press space when ready")
message1.draw()
mywin.update()
response = event.waitKeys(keyList = ['space',], timeStamped = True)#wait for 
subjects to state they are ready

#Cities block
#First trial 

print Stim_text
del Stim_text[1,2]
print Stim_text
```

I am fairly sure it will involve changing the attributes of the loop- as otherwise it would not make sense to have so many lists.

Nathan

Comment: You should look into the TrialHandler class http://www.psychopy.org/api/data.html#psychopy.data.TrialHandler which will handle a lot of the drudgery for you for free (storing and saving data, and so on). Check the Coder demos for how to use it. It can read the positions and other variables from an external conditions file (e.g. .csv or .xlsx), which can be easier to edit and maintain than typing the conditions as hard-coded lists within your code.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would do something like this:

```py
# Run the code inside this loop four times
for block in range(4):
    for i, position in enumerate(positions):
        # Prepare stimulus
        Target.pos = position
        Target.text = Stim_text[i]

        # Show it 
        Target.draw()
        win.flip()

        # Collect response and score it
        key = event.waitKeys(keyList=['q', 'p'])[0]  # Just get the first response key
        # Save response here somehow.
```

As Mike pointed out in a comment, look into `psychopy.data.TrialHandler` which can do much of this for you, including saving data. Also, there's no need to generate a new `visual.TextStim` for each message. Just update the text of an existing one with the desired text.